# Checking if table cell blocks have data and if so change the styling

Tags: javascript, php, css, if-statement, html-table

I created a table that I am using as a draft board. There are users and then players they have to pick. I am wondering if a user has picked a player if there is anyway I can style that cell block in a different color style to show that block more significantly that it was picked. Then the empty blocks leave the normal styling.

I created a fiddle to show the table somewhat how it looks.

https://jsfiddle.net/zmggLd57/

So the cells that have names in them I was wondering if I could make them a different color.

```
<table class="draft_border_table">
<tr>
    <th class="draft_table_number_th">RND</th>
<?php
// Output usernames as column headings
$userResults = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM user_players ORDER BY `id`');
while ($userPlayer = mysqli_fetch_array($userResults)) {
    $userPlayerStore[] = $userPlayer;
    echo '<th class="draft_table_th"><div>' . $userPlayer['username'] . '</div></th>';
}
?>
</tr>
<?php
// Output each user's player 1-14 in each row
$totalPlayerNumbers = 14;
for ($playerNum = 1; $playerNum <= $totalPlayerNumbers; $playerNum++) {
    echo '<tr><td><div class="draftBorder">' . $playerNum . '</div></td>';
    foreach ($userPlayerStore as $userPlayer) {
        echo '<td class="draft_table_td">' . $userPlayer['player' . $playerNum] . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: so, you ain't using jQuery ?

Comment: I will use anything to get it done. I just didn't know if it was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope, it will help you

```
$("td.draft_table_td").each(function(){
if($(this).text()!=""){
$(this).css("background-color","blue");
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7w3c384f/

Comment: I don't want to have to click the cell though. I just want it to check if the cell is filled and then apply a different style

Comment: try this.$("td.draft_table_td").each(function(){

if($(this).text()!=""){
    $(this).css("background-color","blue");
}

});

Comment: Great! One other question that directly relates to this.. What if this expanded a bit in this manner. What if some of the table cells said `Tom - A` `Bob - B`, is there a way to search if the cell is filled and then sub-search for the letter A and B. Then something like giving A the color red and then B the color blue?

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra css class for the filled in or blank table cells.

```
...
foreach ($userPlayerStore as $userPlayer) {
    if (empty($userPlayer['player'.$playerNum])){
       $extra_class = 'emptycell';
    }else{
       $extra_class = 'filledcell';
    }

    echo '<td class="draft_table_td '.$extra_class.'">' .
          $userPlayer['player' .  $playerNum] . '</td>';
}
```

then add the appropriate styling in your .css

```
 td.draft_table_td.emptycell {
     background: red;
 }
```

Comment: It's not working for me... `foreach ($userPlayerStore as $userPlayer) {
   if (empty($userPlayer['player'.$playerNum])){
     $extra_class = 'emptycell';
  }else{
     $extra_class = 'filledcell';
  }
        echo '<td class="draft_table_td">' . $userPlayer['player' . $playerNum] . '</td>';` ...and css ....`td.draft_table_td.emptycell{
 background-color: #606060;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 width: 14%;
 text-align: center;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
td.draft_table_td.filledcell{
 background-color: #606060;
 color: red;
 width: 14%;
 text-align: center;
 border: 1px solid black;
}`

Comment: Did you add the css that Loopo added ?